# Should I use a design pattern in simple activities in android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, android-mvp

I am android developer. I am using MVP design pattern in my app. I have some simple layouts in my app I think that it won't a problem to make them without the pattern is this thing accepted or it is a bad practise and I have to avoid doing this

Comment: yes, it will be published

Comment: Then yes, use MVP, but not just for it to be used, use it for current unit testing and further maintenance.

Comment: Ignore design patterns (especially MV** since android was never built to fit one of them), rather look at the examples at https://developer.android.com/guide/ and try to determine best practices from there.

Comment: @zapl that is actually interesting. Can you provide more detailed explanation?

Comment: @Yupi e.g. https://plus.google.com/+DianneHackborn/posts/FXCCYxepsDU - android itself is not designed with the intention to be some MV*, best practice has basically always been whatever works well with the android framework. You can move a little towards your favorite MV* pattern but it's usually not going to be ideal because the framework is in the way. We have now (MVVM) architecture components now but even with them, you're still bound by the framework and trying too hard to press it into a pattern won't give you a better app. Do "android" first, then pattern

Comment: Thanks @zapl this was very useful and interesting.